# ios 9 objective-c screen size issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ios9

I upgrade to ios 9 and xcode 7 (from xcode 6.2) and now this happens when I start my app:

[image]

There is now all this black bars above and below.

My appDelegate is like so:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    // [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];



    _startViewController = [[StartViewController alloc] init];
    _startNavigationController = [[StartNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_startViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = _startNavigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Need to fix this since deprecated
    // [application prefersStatusBarHidden:NO];
    // [application preferredS :UIStatusBarStyleDefault];

    // [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing the correct launch screens sizes. You should use image assets and fill all the required sizes.

Comment: Have you integrate all the splash screens with correct dimensions? If no, then please do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

case was missing the **LaunchScreen.storyboard** in General setting under App icons and launch images:

[image]

above function is not work check  the follow the below steps:

1. Navigate to project settings
2. Under "App Icons and Launch Images" click on "Use Asset Catalog"
3. Select "Migrate" on the popup that appears.

This should fix the issue.

[image]

Comment: I hadn't set up launch images in my ios 7 app. I guess it is mandatory now for ios 9?

Comment: Yes, it is mandatory. Please set up launch images with correct dimensions. Without this Xcode is making an assumption about your screen size.

Comment: Adding in the LaunchScreen.storyboard and setting it up worked. Thx

Answer (score 3):

First of all please add these images at your Images.xcassets directory.
You can also change these images but be careful to keep sizes and titles :)

Name them with their titles.
**Default.png**

[image: Default.png]

**Default-Portrait-736h@3x.png**

[image: Default-Portrait-736h@3x.png]

**Default-667h@2x.png**

[image: Default-667h@2x.png]

**Default-568h.png**

[image: Default-568h.png]

Then select LaunchImage at General : App Icons and Launch Images : Launch Images Source

Answer (score 1):

Check your project if it has `LaunchScreen.storyboard` file. Without this Xcode is making an assumption about your screen size. Create a `LaunchScreen.storyboard` file and add it to your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add any splash screen if it doesn't serve any purpose like if it is white or black in that case you can simply add launchScreen.xib and select it Launch screen file option Target setting.