# Xcode/iOS Simulator not showing the app on fullscreen

Tags: ios, xcode7

I had this problem after I updated my Xcode to version 7.0.1

when I run the app on the simulator the bottom part of the app is not showing!.

this is screenshot of the simulator:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/e8cn14mxl7zgk58/Screenshot%202015-10-06%2009.49.25.png?dl=0

Comment: have u checked with iPhone5S simulator

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964581/ios-9-objective-c-screen-size-issues/32964725#32964725

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running your app from xcode 7. You can try it with simulator of iOS 9.0 SDK. That might work for you.

or otherwise check with your launch images. whether you have added launch screen for iPhone 6 or not in image assets.

Comment: Thank you, and this link is very useful http://oleb.net/blog/2014/08/replacing-launch-images-with-storyboards/

Answer (score 1):

I've  had this problem when i didn't provide the correct launch screens for iPhone 5 (In your case iPhone 6). Check that, and if you can, i recommend using a xib for launch screen.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes It happens due to unordered items in Document Outline.

Make sure,It should follow this sequence in document outline.

1) View Controller Scene --> Top layout guide --> Bottom Layout guide --> View --> Navigation item.

2) First Responder

3) Exit