# Could not load "images" referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.myapp"

Tags: ios, iphone, png, asset-catalog, uiimageasset

I'm having a little strange problem. After update Xcode to the seventh version (I suspect that is related with this) I lost all my images on my assets catalog.

The app isn't loading the assets on simulator neither devices, all the images loads fail with the message of the title (my app is almost blank). I've tried removing the catalog and adding a new one, and also inspecting broken references into the storyboard but all that seems to be ok. I don't think the format of the images is the problem because in a near past the app was working well.

I tried a lot of things, clean, removing derived data but nothing work. 
Any help is really appreciated, I'm really stuck on this.

Comment: try adding images separately

Comment: hi Try this link if your facing this kind of issue means http://stackoverflow.com/a/32964725/5362916

Comment: Is there any possibility that your PNG images have been converted to CgBI images by the Xcode "pngcrush" compressor?  Use "pngcheck -v file.png" or "identify file.png" to find out.

Comment: Seems to be that the issue is local to my XCode. A partner cloned the project into your machine and run out of the problems.

Comment: I've cloned again the repo too but no luck