# App compiled with Xcode 6 runs on iPhone 5s top/bottom of screen blank

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Recently we switched to Xcode 6, and I am having this issue: my simplest tabbed app compiled with Xcode 6 occupies just part of the screen, when it runs on iPhone 5s. There are two black strips sitting at the top and bottom of the screen. Like below:

[image: Screenshot]

By default, it looks that way (that is, I created the project using Xcode's template, and compiled and ran it without any modifications). I have also tinkered with various project setting bits, but in vain. Tried creating the project in both Swift and OC, both had the same issue. Never had this problem in Xcode 5.

Can anyone tell what's going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ios 9 objective-c screen size issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964581/ios-9-objective-c-screen-size-issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up launch images in your app. It is mandatory now for ios 9. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18913189/3051458

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you dont have the right image assets in your project. 
Correctly again drag drop the correct image assets in your project (check the splash images) and it will work.

Dont know why this happened but I suffered from this too ones and then saw the splash images got deleted.