# Black bars displayed at the bottom of the screen when using a launch screen

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have a black bar problem with my display. Before I added `main.storyboard` in the Launch Screen File, there are two bars at the top and bottom, but when I used File Launch Screen, there are two bars downstairs. This display on my screen:

[image]

My question is how do I remove the two bars downstairs? knowing that I have to use File Launch Screen and if I do not use File Launch Screen, I have another error (itm of 900,096) when I export my project.

Summary :

- Not Launch Screen File: my project works fine, but I can not export to iTunes.
- Screen with Launch File: there are two bars at the bottom of my screen.

So, how can I remove the two bars downstairs?

I am using an iPhone 5 (iOS 9.2) & Xcode 7.2

Comment: Refer my previous post here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34605761/3051458

Comment: but this is not the same I have a black bar in bottom after adding main.storyboard

Comment: Not related to **Main.storyboard** ; related to **LaunchScreen.storyboard**.

Comment: the same with LaunchScreen.storyboard, I got the same error.

Comment: I will insist that you are running in screen emulation mode, and that your application is not covering the screen. Start a fresh new project to convince yourself.

Answer (score 0):

From far, the easiest way is to create a new project, with a **LaunchScreen.storyboard**, and copy the settings over.

In essence, you want to replace your old launch screen images by a storyboard. It will look something like this:

- Storyboard > Show the File inspector > Use as Launch Screen
- Storyboard > View Controller > Show the Attributes inspector > Is Initial View Controller
- Project > General > Deployment Info > Main Interface > LaunchScreen
- Repeat for [iPhone] and [iPad]
- Project > General > App Icons and Launch Images > Launch Screen File > LaunchScreen

If setup properly, your `Info.plist` should have *LaunchScreen .storyboard*, without the `.storyboard` under the **UILaunchStoryboardName & UIMainStoryboardFile** properties:

```
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>
```

Comment: I use the new LaunchScreen.storyboard and  I have followed the stage but I had the same problem

Comment: The answer above is specifically about not running in screen emulation mode. It appears that whatever views you have added on either the LaunchScreen.storyboard or Main.storyboard may be missing constraints, specifically to stretch to all sides of their containers.

Comment: thank you again for your answer, in my application, I use the camera to take a photo in order to analyze the photo, I shows nothing on the storyboard hand so do if possible to remove the two bars or not? because I do not see, he is possessed the problem in the application for iphone 3.5 inchs it works very well.